# Prove $|f(z)|\leq C$ whenever $|z|\leq 1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a analytic function. Suppose $f(0)=1$ and $f(z)\notin(-\infty,0]$ for all $z\in D$. Prove that there exists a constant $C$ independent of $f$ such that $|f(z)|\leq C$ whenever $|z|\leq 1/2$.

I try to use $\log f(z)$ and then apply the Schwartz lemma. But obviously, we don't have boundedness on the unit disk.

Comment: just a thought: look at $\log(f(z))$ so that you *do* have something bounded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using $\log$, we should use a transformation that maps $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ to something bounded like a disk. In stages:
$z\to \sqrt{z}$ maps that region to the right half-plane.
$z\to \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ maps the right half-plane to the unit disk.
Compose them, and $z\to \frac{\sqrt{z}-1}{\sqrt{z}+1}$ maps that region to the unit disk. So, then, consider the function
$$g(z)=\frac{\sqrt{f(z)}-1}{\sqrt{f(z)}+1}$$
which maps $D$ to $D$, and apply the Schwarz lemma to $g$. Once we have a bound for $g$ on the smaller disk, invert the map to find out what the bound is for $f$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!